# Laravel - how to create and update fields from multiple tables relation laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a relation from two models, when a user create a comment I need to store in a table and update a status field in other table, this should be in the same form submit comment. I getting error Undefined variable: id

**My controller**

```
 public function reply($id)
    {
    if (Auth::check())
        {
        $issue = Issue::where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
        $company = $issue->company;
        $interaction = $issue->interaction;
        return view('issues.reply', compact('issue', 'company', 'interaction'));
        }
      else
        {
        return redirect()->guest('/logon');
        }
    }

public function postComment(Request $request)
    {
    $this->validate($request, ['description' => '']);
    $interaction = IssueInteraction::create(['issue_report_id' => $request->input('issue_report_id') , 'user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'description' => $request->input('description') , 'owner' => 'USER', ]);
    if ($interaction->save())
        {
        $issue = Issue::where('id', $id)->findOrFail->id;
        $issue->updateOrCreate->status = $request->status;
        $issue->save();
        }

    $interaction->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
    return redirect()->back()->with("status", "Your reply has be submitted.");
    }
```

**My route**

```
Route::get('/account/issues/{id}', 'IssueInteractionController@reply');
Route::post('interaction', 'IssueInteractionController@postComment');
```

**My form**

```
 <form class="form-secondary" action="{{ url('/interaction') }}" method="POST">
   {!! csrf_field() !!}
   <input type="hidden" name="issue_report_id" value="{{ $issue->id }}">
   <textarea rows="10" id="description" class="form-control" name="description"></textarea>
   <input type="hidden" id="status" name="status" value="2">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary shadow mt-4">@lang('app.Send Reply')</button>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: At which line (file) ? Provide exact error message.

Comment: `$issue = Issue::where('id', $id)->findOrFail->id;` you don't actually set the `$id` variable anywhere, that's why you get errors.

Comment: it seems you´re right but I tried everything and I can't make it work, I need to update column status from Issue model when user create a comment from form Interaction model they have relation, it's storing interaction and comment but it's not updating status from Issue model.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking to change in your postComment() method. That is, if the issue_report_id is the corresponding key to the Issue model's id.

```
    $issue = Issue::where('id', $interaction->issue_report_id)->first()->id;
```

Comment: I tried to use this code but it give me a error Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$findOrFail

Comment: I updated the code. I forgot to change findOrFail to first().

Comment: Thanks for reply, but now I getting error Attempt to modify property of non-object for the line  $issue->updateOrCreate->status = $request->status; I have try a lot things and nothing seems to work :(

Comment: It should be $issue->updateOrCreate(['status' => $request->status]);   and if that doesn't work, please code dd($request); and post the output here. We are close to getting it working.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did it work with  Issue::where('id', $interaction->issue_report_id)->update([
               "status"     => $request->status,
            ]); works like a charm! :)